# C++ Kill all parents child threads from a child thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a C++ program that starts two threads from the parent thread, I need to kill both children from a child thread.

Main's children are b and c.

I need to kill b & c from b. Issue is, I can't use simple flags, as c waits for input using cin.
I tried using terminate from within b with the hopes that the whole main loop would restart.

Here is the code I have, I need to kill t1 and t2 from t1.

```
void recieve_(){

    //STEP 5 recieving
    while (!restart){
        iRecv = recv(TCPClientSocket, RecvBuffer, iRecvBuffer, 0);
        if (iRecv == SOCKET_ERROR){
            int err = WSAGetLastError();
            cout << "recv failed: " << err << endl;
            if (err == WSAECONNRESET){
                cout << "server disconnected" << endl;
                system("deletesockclient.exe");
            }
            Sleep(300);
        }
        else{
            cout << "Recieved: " << RecvBuffer << endl;
        }
    }
}
void send_(){

    //STEP 6 send data to server
    while (!restart){
        cout << "Enter message: ";
        string s;
        cin >> s;
        cout << endl;
        strcpy(SenderBuffer, s.c_str());
        iSend = send(TCPClientSocket, SenderBuffer, iSenderBuffer, 0);
        if (iSend == SOCKET_ERROR){
            cout << "sending failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        }
        cout << "sent successfully" << endl;
    }
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    while (true){
        init();
        thread t1(recieve_);
        thread t2(send_);
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        //STEP 7 close socket
        iCloseSocket = closesocket(TCPClientSocket);
        closesocket(TCPClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Its never a good idea to terminate threads. To abort std::cin you might under windows try using SendInput to simulate Ctrl-Z which should abort it. You might also try moving std::cin to some another worker thread, and in your b or c thread wait for its output with timeout. You still will have a hanging thread with std::cin inside but maybe this will work for you.

Comment: Terminating a thread put your whole program into Undefined Behaviour territory.

Comment: Threads don't have a parent-child relationship in general. That said, there are literally hundreds of questions asking how to terminate a thread here. Please do a bit of research.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find the solution, but removed the problem. integrated the send void with the main thread so receive thread just had to kill itself, not both "child" threads.